# calculating percentage group by group in a column R

Tags: r, statistics

Again I'm absolutely new in R and trying to sort a problem I faced to sort.
I have a data set "ds" with column "group" and "match"
I need to calculate percentage of column match group per group
the first group would be **001** second group is **002**, third one **003**, and so on.

I have now a data :

```
>ds

group   col1    col2       match  
 001       F       M       FALSE   
 001       F       M       FALSE    
 001       F       M       FALSE    
 002       F       M       FALSE 
 002       M       M       TRUE    
 003       M       F       FALSE
 003       F       F       TRUE    
 003       F       F       TRUE    
 003       F       M       FALSE    
 004       F       M       FALSE 
 005       F       F       TRUE 
 005       M       F       FALSE    
 005       M       M       TRUE    
 006       M       M       TRUE         
 006       F       M       FALSE 
 006       F       M       FALSE
 006       F       M       FALSE
 006       F       M       FALSE
 006       F       F       TRUE
 006       F       M       FALSE 
 006       F       M       FALSE



Desired result:


group | col1   |  col2  |  match  | mismatch % | Match %
 001       F       M       FALSE        1.0         0    
 001       F       M       FALSE    
 001       F       M       FALSE    
 002       F       M       FALSE        0.50       0.50
 002       M       M       TRUE    
 003       M       F       FALSE        0.50       0.50
 003       F       F       TRUE    
 003       F       F       TRUE    
 003       F       M       FALSE    
 004       F       M       FALSE        1.0        0
 005       F       F       TRUE         0.66       0.33
 005       M       F       FALSE    
 005       M       M       TRUE    
 006       M       M       TRUE         
 006       F       M       FALSE        0.75       0.25
 006       F       M       FALSE
 006       F       M       FALSE
 006       F       M       FALSE
 006       F       F       TRUE
 006       F       M       FALSE 
 006       F       M       FALSE
```

I know how to calculate if for entire column:

```
percentage <- table(ds$match)
cbind(percentage,prop.table(percentage))
```

but can't  adopt it for my solution shown higher

Thanks

Comment: Do you just want `prop.table(table(ds$group,ds$match), 1)` ?

Comment: Hi theletemail , thanks for your answer, it seem your solution does calculates percentage by groups for column match, but question is :) how to do set it in the way it is in desired format ?

Comment: You could do something like `ds$match_per <- with(ds, ave(match, group, FUN=function(x) c(sum(x)/length(x), rep(NA,length(x)-1))))` but that seems a bit wasteful to have all the empty cells.

Comment: Thanks theletemail,  It works, but strange is that,  sometimes it calculates as 0.0000000  sometimes as 0 :) same with 1's and 1.0000000   can't see the dependence.....    you are right about empty rows, but I need all to be formatted that way to keep number of rows, to add variables later on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be one way to do it with `dplyr`

We can take advantage of 2 things here: you have a column full of true/false values and the fact that the amount of mismatch you have is just 1 minus the proportion of matches.

```
library(dplyr)
# test data
data <- data.frame(group = factor(c(1,1,1,2,2)), col1 = c(1,1,1,1,0), col2 = c(0,0,0,0,0),
               match = c(F,F,F,F,T))

# group by group, then sum the T/F vector and divide by the number of data
# points per group
desired <- data %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(Match_per = sum(match)/length(match))

# the mismatch is 1 minus the match
desired$Mismatch <- 1 - desired$Match

data$Match_percent <- NA
data$Mismatch_percent <- NA
data[which(duplicated(data$group) == FALSE),
which(colnames(data) %in%c("Match_percent", 
    "Mismatch_percent"))] <- desired[,=1]
```

output

```
  group col1 col2 match Match_percent Mismatch_percent
1     1    1    0 FALSE           0.0              1.0
2     1    1    0 FALSE            NA               NA
3     1    1    0 FALSE            NA               NA
4     2    1    0 FALSE           0.5              0.5
5     2    0    0  TRUE            NA               NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer M_Fido, sorry I may ask a stupid question but :) how exactly shall I use this solution to create some like shown in desired result and keep that particular format?     for a simple group per group calculation this works  too: prop.table(table(ds$group,ds$match), 1)

Comment: I updated the code to keep the type of format that you wanted.

Comment: No problem! Please accept the answer if it worked for you.